# httperf: connection failed with unexpected error 0

Tags: ssl, httperf

Has anybody seen "httperf: connection failed with unexpected error 0" when running httperf with --ssl?

This is blocking my test on that domain. When I tested --ssl on https://google.com it worked fine.

On the other end of my "problematic" domain there is ELB, forwarding calls to heroku.

On my workstation: OSX 10.9.5 and httperf-0.9.0 (via brew)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, by looking at NGINX logs it turns out the SSL handshake fails because SSLv3 is disabled server side.

The project seemed a bit dead so I modified [this file](https://code.google.com/p/httperf/source/browse/trunk/httperf/src/httperf.c) at line 924 :

I replaced `SSLv3_client_method()` with `TLSv1_client_method()`

Then the usual compilation stuff *configure-make-install*. Be sure to have openssl on your build machine.

Source : https://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_new.html

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @oto turned out be related to my fix as well. Basically, we stopped using SSLv3 on our server (and, apparently, all other ssl protocols used by httperf) due to the [POODLE](https://poodle.io/servers.html) vulnerability, and httperf uses SSLv3, so it fails to connect.

Until they update httperf there seems to be no easy way around this. One way to fix it is to change from SSLv3 to TLSv1 by hand, as mentioned in the other answer.

I found [this patch pull-request](https://github.com/httperf/httperf/issues/8) on GitHub. It changes the code so you can specify the ssl protocol with a flag, so I could force using TLSv1 instead of SSLv3.

For both fixes you will need to download the [httperf source code](https://github.com/httperf/httperf), make the changes (like applying the [patch](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_patch.htm)), and then compile.  I cloned the source from GitHub, so I had to run the `autoreconf -i` command before running `make`, but [the instructions](https://github.com/httperf/httperf#building-httperf) are pretty good. I had to use commit ed5c631 since the latest commits appear to be broken.